# "Intent" vs. "intention"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences, word-usage

How are *intent* and *intention* distinguished in terms of usage?

My guess after checking my pocket dictionary is

*Intent* is used to mean a bad purpose.

> Their intent to kill the boy is crystal clear!

*Intention* is used in other cases.

> Their intention is to enjoy seeing the cashflow.

Comment: This link is better http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/language/askaboutenglish/2009/02/090203_aae_intention.shtml

Answer (score 11):

This is taken from a [site](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=46137) similar to this:

> "Intention is the general word implying a having something in mind as a plan or design, or referring to the plan had in mind. Intent, a somewhat formal term now largely in legal usage, connotes more deliberation (assault with an intent to kill)"
>
> Thus, an *intention* is a general plan that one has in mind. An *intent* is really a deliberate plan.

Comment: Any view on OP's hunch that "intent" has negative connotations?

Answer (score 3):

"Intention is the general word implying a having something in mind as a plan or design, or referring to the plan had in mind. Intent, a somewhat formal term now largely in legal usage, connotes more deliberation (assault with an intent to kill)"

That explanation is certainly better than mine, and I find it true.

Edit: You asked for sentences; sorry.

My intention was to buy a long dress to wear as a guest at the wedding. However, after shopping awhile, I didn't find any styles of long dresses that I liked, so I bought a short one instead.

Our apartment building has a strict policy of no pets. My neighbor, George, rarely visits me. So when he knocked at my door this morning, I just knew his intent was to find my cat!

Thus, an intention is a general plan that one has in mind. An intent is really a deliberate plan.

[get information](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/blog.php?action=ViewBlogArticle&ba_id=78)

[also use this link](http://www.english-test.net/forum/ftopic742.html)

Answer (score -1):

**Intention projects larger purpose of accomplishing an idea,while an intent is a purpose for an special /particular project.**strong text****